# testdroid plugin does not show up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testdroid

I am trying to install testdroid recorder plugin on the latest Android ADT on Mac OS X 10.7. I am following all the steps listed on the site. The plugin gets successfully installed according to the messages displayed. I have also confirmed the same by going to "install new software" and viewing the site "http://testdroid.com/updates".
However, it does not show up in the Preferences tab as well as the new> others tab, where I do not see any option like Android Testdroid>.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testdroid Recorder since version 4.4.18 requires java 7 installed, so you have to update it to be able to use the plugin.